# Help proving a theorem on uniform continuity in an open interval

Tags: calculus, functions, uniform-continuity

I need help proving that given f:(a,b)→R that is uniformly continuous, it is possible to extend f to f:[a,b]→R that is continuous on the closed interval.

thanks in advance!

Comment: If f is continuous on a closed interval <=> uniformly continuous on closed interval. So just extend with continuity from the left and right

Comment: @AlecTeal I think the OP's question is *exactly* that: how to "extend with continuity" on both ends. Observe this can **not** be done if we only take a continuous function on an open interval, so the question could be put, perhaps, as: what does *uniform* continuity gives us extra that we can do this, and **how** can this be done?

Comment: Let $x_n\rightarrow b$ with $x_n\in(a,b)$. Show $(f(x_n))$ is a Cauchy sequence. Then show its limit is independent of the particular sequence chosen. Let $f(b)$ be the value of this limit.

Comment: Exactly, that's how you show uniform continuity from continuity @DavidMitra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints using the comment by David:

Show that the limits

$$\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)\;\;,\;\;\;\;\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)$$

exist *finitely*, and then extend the definition of $\;f\;$ on those end points accordingly.

For example: if $\;\epsilon>0\;$ , we know that there exists $\;\delta>0\;$ s.t.

$$\left(x,y\in (a,b)\;\;\wedge\;\;|x-y|<\delta\right)\;\implies\; |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$$

The above is true *also* in any right neighborhood of $\;a\;$ (contained in $\;(a,b)\;$, of course), so deduce that for **any** sequence

$$\;\left(\{x_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\subset (a,b)\;\;s.t.\;\;x_n\to a\right)\implies \{f(x_n)\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$$

converges *finitely* since it is a **Cauchy sequence**, say to $\;L\;$ , and then just put $\;f(a):=L\;$ .

Comment: You put special effort into it, but I personally find the extra  `\;` spacing  around formulas confusing

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen In what sense *exactly* is that confusing? In particular, if you don't click on "edit" to read the coding...? And I do this to avoid "crowding" of symbols, and imo it comes up a little clearer, but of course: this may dependon each one.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I got it.